# Operand Error Message when Summing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following statement in my query and I am receiving an error:

```
 SUM(isnull((T1.RecvQty),0)) '3rd Party Received Qty',
 SUM(isnull((T0.Quantity-T0.Quantout),0)) 'SAP Onhand',  
 SUM(isnull((T1.recvQty),0)- isnull((T0.Quantity-T0.QuantOut),0)) as 'Varience',
```

Error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: This is a TSQL database

Answer (score 0):

The error should be obvious.

Based on the error message, I assume you are using SQL Server.  Just use `try_convert()`:

```
SUM(TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 4), T1.RecvQty)) as [3rd Party Received Qty],
```

I am guessing at a valid numeric representation for the value.

EDIT:

If you don't want `NULL` returned, then use `COALESCE()` *after* the aggregation:

```
COALESCE(SUM(TRY_CONVERT(NUMERIC(20, 4), T1.RecvQty)), 0)
```

This is usually not necessary, because `SUM()` ignores `NULL` values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The issue with this is that nulls return as a null value. I had the isnull in the formula so that if the value was null it returned a 0. I need the nulls to return as 0s to calculate the variance properly.